# Add view created dynamically to convertview in expandable listview android

Tags: expandablelistadapter, convertview

This is my first question, I need to add dynamically `textViews` to `convertView` that is returned in `getChildView()` method expandable, but I can not do in any way..

```
   @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderChild holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_line, null);
            holder = new ViewHolderChild();
            holder.txNumeroSolicitacao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumeroSolicitacao);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txNumeroSolicitacao.setText(String.valueOf(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).getNumero()));


    //if my log list isn't empty, I want add a textview dynamically to view     
        if(!getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).getLog().isEmpty()) {

            holder.textViewResponse = new TextView(context);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alignParentLeft = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            alignParentLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            holder.textViewResponse.setLayoutParams(alignParentLeft);
            ((ViewGroup) convertView).addView(holder.textViewResponse);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

But I can not add the `textView` to `convertView`. The application always returns unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You might add the TextView in child_line.xml with android:visibility="gone", and set it's visibility in getChildView according to if the current line's bound object's log is empty.